# How to use writeFromExistingFile(File,boolean) method of Dropbox SYNC API?

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am writing to a DbxFile from a SD CARD file using writeFromExistingFile(File,boolean) method.But it does not work and gives the Cross link error mentioning that it cannot write from SDCARD to the DbxFileSystem cache. Can anyone give the details of proper usage of this method? Also can I copy .db file from SDcard to the DbxFile system because I do not want to use DataStore API?
Error which I got while writing was - **E/libDropboxSync.so(ERR)(11250): DROPBOX_ERROR_SYSTEM: file.cpp:737: moving /storage/emulated/0/sync_sdk.txt to cache: Cross-device link**

Comment: A good start to asking this question would be to tell us the actual error you get (like the full exception trace). "Cross link error" is pretty vague.

Comment: @smarx - I have posted the error here also.Kindly refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

That message indicates errno==EXDEV after a call to rename() (http://linux.die.net/man/3/rename).  That seems to indicate that the source file is a link, which can't be made to work across volumes (e.g. between SD card and internal storage).  Is that the case here?  There's a prior check which would've rejected symlinks, but it could be a hard-link.  Or the docs might just be misleading, and this could simply be an issue with moving a file between volumes.

In general, using the shouldSteal option to move a link into the API cache is going to cause problems, since the cache expects to have unique ownership of the file.  You should probably set shouldSteal=false, which will cause the DbxFile to make a copy of your input file instead (after which you can delete it if you wish).  That should work regardless of whether the input is a link, or where the input is, so long as it's readable.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success coping and image(jpg) from my SD card to Dropbox using this:

```
DbxFileSystem dbxFiles = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(accountManager.getLinkedAccount());
    //Get the Source
File pictureFile = new File("/sdcard/<Your SD Path>/<Your SD File>");
    //Tell it were you want it
DbxFile bitMap = dbxFiles.create(new DbxPath("<Dbx Path>/<Dbx File>"));
    //write it there
bitMap.writeFromExistingFile(pictureFile, false);
```

Replace what's in the <> with your info